# How to cache an arbitrary object in Rails(time-based)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, redis

I read the official guide. It says there are `page cache`, `action cache` and `fragment cache`, but they are not what I want.

I just like to cache an object, not the whole page or fragment of view, like this pseudocode:

```
def show
  cache @ads, :expires_in => 1.hour do
    @ads = Advertisement.all
  do
end
```

Is it possible? with `memcache` or `redis`?

Comment: Caching objects means serialization (usually through Marshal.dump/Marshal.load). Be careful as some objects cannot be serialized. Some others have large object graphs (attributes and variables that point to other, large, objects) which can be both expensive to serialize/unserialize and can take up a lot more space than you expect. For example, "caching" `ActiveRecord` objects by serializing them to redis/memcache is **not** a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#To cache the object
Rails.cache.write('cache-key', object)

#Load the object from the cache
Rails.cache.read('cache-key')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [lawnchair gem](https://github.com/gizm0duck/lawnchair) to cache objects in Redis.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.cache.write(cache_key, your_value, expires_in: 10.seconds)

Rails.cache.readh(cache_key)
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on your code a bit more, maybe by explaining it?